# Have Outlook use a non-standard account when working in a given folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I have a situation where I want to have Outlook manage a Hotmail account in addition to the usual one using the Outlook Connector.  This is to subscribe to mailing lists, where it is important to use a non-sensitive email address.

Normally Outlook works with the sensitive email address which is fine, but when I am placed in the Hotmail folder I'd REALLY like it to default to the non-sensitive account.  Currently I need to switch manually which will fail some day, and my initial guessing at what this might be called in the online help failed.

Can this be done?  What is it called in Outlook-speak?

Thanks.

Comment: So you have two Hotmail accounts set up in Outlook. The non-sensitive one uses Outlook Connector or both?!? And you want Outlook to redirect you to the non-sensitive by default, but it's not your default mail address?